# Api en Ruby on Rails: ¿Puedo agregar diferentes métodos GET de una entidad?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, rest

Al generar el controlador y las rutas, tengo que hacer un metodo Create, Update, Index, Show que representan a los diferentes verbos HTTP, GET, POST PUT.

Mi duda es que pasa si por ejemplo en el método index consulto un listado de todos los usuarios, pero quiero otro método que me de los mejores 10 usuarios y otro en donde me de los usuarios de un rol en especifico, tengo que configurar y generar las rutas para cada una de esas acciones o que es lo correcto?

En caso de ser posible configurar las rutas para tener mas acciones del metodo GET, como lo explico arriba cual es la manera de hacerlo con Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Creo que es una buena pregunta, pero no esta relacionada con rubi ni rails, es puramente una pregunta de REST.

Comment: Creo que no me explique bien, soy nuevo en Ruby on Rails y tengo la duda de si es posible hacer eso y como seria hacerlo con rails. Es decir agregar mas métodos aparte del index para consultar una lista de usuarios.

Comment: Puedes agregar parámetros opcionales al index para especificar el rol y/o la columna de ordenamiento y/o la cantidad dé registros. Estas funciones son reutilizables.

Comment: Excelente! Ya esta entendido, muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo de muchas maneras, yo te voy a explicar las dos más sencillas:

1. Mediante algún tipo de filtro en tu acción `index`
2. Creando nuevas rutas y acciones de tu controlador

***Mediante algún tipo de filtro en tu acción `index`***

Si estás utilizando `resources :users` en tus rutas puedes agregar un parámetro a tu enlace: `users_path(:user_filter => 'best_ten')`.

Si no usas resources, puedes poner tu link así: `<a href='/users?user_filter=best_ten'>Link </a>` y la entrada en `routes.rb` tendría este aspecto: `get 'users' => 'users#index'`

Entonces en tu controlador puedes saber si estás seleccionando todos o sacando los 10 mejores:

**users_controller.rb**

```
def index
  if params[:user_filter] && params[:user_filter] == 'best_ten'
    @users = User.all.order_by(:score).limit(10) # Aquí iría tu código real
  else
    @users = User.all
  end
end
```

Lo importante es que mandes un parámetro a tu método del controlador, lo cual también puedes comprobar mediante la consola de Rails.

***Creando nuevas rutas y acciones de tu controlador***

El segundo método es menos "restful" pero te puede servir para que el código de los controladores sea más simple, con el inconveniente de que tendrás muchas más acciones, sobre todo si haces muchos filtrados diferentes.

**routes.rb**

```
get 'best_ten_users' => 'users#best_ten'
```

**El enlace a dicho listado en views/users/index.html.erb**

```
<a href='/best_ten_users'> Link </a>
```

**users_controller.rb**

(...)

```
def best_ten
  @users = User.all.order(:score).limit(10)
end
```

(...)

Answer (score 0):

la manera de hacerlo con Rails es sencilla.

```
# config/routes.rb
resources :users do
  collection do
    get "top_ten"
    get "role/:role_name"
  end
end
```

Eso te generará las siguientes rutas en tu aplicación:

```
GET /users
POST /users
GET /users/new
GET /users/:id
PUT /users/:id
GET /users/id/edit
DELETE /users/:id
GET /users/top_ten
GET /users/role/:role_name
```

Answer (score -1):

seria mas onda de REST que de Rails, pero podrías crear un método que reciba esos filtros y retorne los valores al index ó bien agregarlos directamente al método index, bueno es lo que se me ocurre, creo en el Rails for Zombies 2 aplican algo así, saludos.

Comment: Asumiendo que OP es principiante en Rails, esta respuesta no ayuda mucho ya que no hay ejemplos de código y aparte le estás recomendando (de forma dudosa ya que "crees") un curso en el que ni siquiera indicas en que unidad o tema puede encontrar la solución a su problema.